# How to get unix command line in a web application?

Tags: java, unix, web-applications, command

Here's what I'm looking at doing. I've certain log files on a unix box. The files are in the range of 10-100 MB. What I'm looking at building is have a web application in which I can have the unix command line, where I can type my commands like grep,ls etc and then the output that the command gives can be displayed in a table/gridview in the web app. Is this possible to do? I'm looking at a solution possibly in Java. The only thing I cannot use is Microsoft stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the web SSH clients listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH

Answer (score 0):

java [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) can help you. It will allow you to create process and execute the command inside the process and get the results back.